# bower installs uikit source

Tags: bower, getuikit

I used to install uikit (2.27.2) with a simple `bower install uikit` and I always got the compiled version. Now I cleared my bower cache and I get the uncompiled source (no css files, only less). Does anyone know why this is?

My current workaround is:
`bower install https://github.com/uikit/bower-uikit.git`

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, i got normal sources with this command.  For simpler download i would use bower install uikit#2.72.2

Comment: Maybe show us comand line output or directory listening. The bower uikit repo seems deprecated, maybe problem lies there. Although new uikit installs with bower, something could have changed.